# Error missing MySQL extension

Tags: mysql, errors

Yesterday I delete some files to clean up my storage. After that, I face the following error while visiting my website.

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
> is required by WordPress.

I delete my WordPress Old Setup and Install New one, but the problem still exists. What's the possible solution to recover my website. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this will require server level changes, this isn't something you can fix by changing PHP files. Your host needs to install the mysqli PHP extension

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I appreciate it. @Tom J Nowell